# Bind shift-tab to complete-backward in fish

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, autocomplete, fish

I found myself using the auto-complete functionality of the fish-shell, where pressing tab twice or more cycles through the suggestions. But then I accidentaly pressed tab once to many, and I wanted to go back to the previous suggestion, so I pressed shift-tab, which only appended `[z` to the command.

For example, when I type `cd D`<kbd>tab</kbd><kbd>tab</kbd>:

```
~> cd Desktop/
```

I press <kbd>tab</kbd>, result:

```
~> cd Documents/
```

Now when I press `<shift+tab>`, the prompt changes to `~> cd Documents/[Z` instead of returning to the desired:

```
~> cd Desktop/
```

How do I do this (preferably using the `fish_user_key_bindings.fish` file)? [The documentation](http://fishshell.com/docs/current/commands.html#bind) only provides the special function `complete`.

Comment: Is there not an "undo" or anything?

Answer (score 1):

- As you said  "The documentation only provides the special function complete" .
  you can't go back to previews suggestion  because this feature isn't implemented .
- but for defining a new binding you have to use fish_user_key_binding function NOT .fish file :
  open your configuration file `~/.config/fish/config.fish`

and add :

```
function fish_user_key_bindings
        bind [Z complete
        end
```

- restart your fish , this well bind shift+tab for complete

Comment: I don't need another keybinding for complete, I need a keybinding to go back to the previous suggestion. I guess you're right and it just isn't implemented...

Answer (score -2):

Consider using zsh instead.

The exact details of its autocompleter are of course configurable to your personal tastes, but the way I have it set up is if I press <kbd>Tab</kbd> twice, I get a "menu" that I can navigate using the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key or the arrow keys, like so:

[image: ZSH Completion]

Once I've selected the entry I want, I can press Enter to tell zsh this is what I want, or I can just continue typing and zsh will assume that's correct.